# Make a response to a response

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

How do you make a response to a response? Like here I wanted to respond to this. I don't see a comment button.

@Alex @Dogbert This does answer the question, but '-s' can mask problems, e.g. when you use xargs with grep. Try creating 2 files in a dir, 'aaa.txt' and 'a b.txt', both containing the string 'some text'. The command /bin/ls -1 | xargs grep 'some text' will give you "no such file or directory" because it breaks up 'a b.txt' into 2 args. If you suppress, you won't notice you missed a file.

[How can I have grep not print out 'No such file or directory' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426363/how-can-i-have-grep-not-print-out-no-such-file-or-directory-errors)

Answer (score 1):

Here on StackOverflow (and anywhere else on the StackExchange network for that sake), there is a privilege system that defines what you're allowed to do.

If you have a look at [Privileges - Comment Everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment), you will see that you need 50 reputation in order to comment on a question that isn't your own. Currently, you only have one reputation point.

You can gain more reputation by actively participating in the community, that means asking and answering question.

In the future, should you have issues regarding the site, please read the FAQ and the page about reputation. If you still have not gotten your answer, you should go to [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) and try asking there - that site deals with questions and answers about using StackOverflow.